# How to properly install select2 (or Chosen - or maybe ANY JS?) in RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails beginner here: I have played around with Chosen and saw some posts that Select2 is the better option. However regardless of which one I am trying to use, I always run into the same error.

I have one of them in the Gemfile and run bundle install, and the gem is then present (I can run bundle info on it).

I then try to include the JS into app/javascript/packs/application.js like so:

```
require ("select2")
```

or

```
require ("chosen-jquery")
```

Whatever I do - my JS console says

```
Cannot find module 'select2'
```

(or chosen-jquery).

I am sure this is a super stupid oversight. I googled like crazy and searched here but could not find anything (which probably means even more that this is a stupid oversicht! :)

Any hint is highly welcomed. I probably don't understand how all this webpacker / JS stuff is working.
Note btw that I WAS able to get easy-autocomplete (and jquery) via YARN and then I CAN actually require easy-autocomplete in application.js (and also the stylesheets in application.scss) via:

```
require("easy-autocomplete")
```

I don't quite get why this one is working and the other ones not?

Here is my full app/javascript/packs/application.js (including autocomplete):

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

require("jquery")
require("easy-autocomplete")

require("select2/dist/css/select2")


document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    var $input = $("[data-behaviour='autocomplete']")

    var options = {
        getValue: "name",
        url: function(phrase) {
            return "/search.json?q=" + phrase;
        },
        categories: [
            {
                listLocation: "movies",
                header: "<strong>Movies</strong>",
            },
            {
                listLocation: "actors",
                header: "<strong>Actors</strong>",
            },
            {
                listLocation: "actoraliases",
                header: "<strong>Actor Aliases</strong>",
            }
        ],
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function() {
                var url = $input.getSelectedItemData().url
                $input.val("")
                Turbolinks.visit(url)
            }
        }
    }

    $input.easyAutocomplete(options)
})

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    $('.selector').select2();
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [select-2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) this is only for the Rails Asset Pipeline.

Try installing `select2` via yarn (opposed to the ruby gem):

```
yarn install select2
```

In `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```js
require("select2/dist/css/select2")

$(".content-search").select2();

// Side Note: when I moved this to a Stimulus Controller `import Select2 from "select2"` was needed.
```

In `app/views/foos/_form.html.erb`:

```rb
<%= form.label :foo_id %>
<%= form.collection_select(:foo_id, Foo.all, :id, :name, { include_blank: true }, class: "content-search") %>
```

Comment: ok perfect. I think I need to understand more about the "rails asset pipeline" but - for now pretty clear, I will install via yarn :) Thank you!

Comment: hm - I need to come back to the "perfect".... because now I get an error message in my js console saying "select2 is not a function"....?

Comment: Make sure you have jquery installed?

Comment: I can run $().jquery; in the javascript console and it returns 3.6.0 ... so I guess that shuld be all ok? I also have another plugin installed - easyAutocomplete - which works just fine (and also uses a tiny bit of jquery...). I have posted my entire app/javascript/packs/application.js file in my original question above

Comment: I have just tried to MANUALLY invoke select2 - as in: I removed the line $(".content-search").select2(); from application.js, then loaded the form page, and manually in the console typed in $(".content-search").select2() - worked PERFECTLY! Now I am really confused... could this be a timing issue?

Comment: Can you show _exactly_ how you had it setup in your application.js?

Comment: My full application.js is posted at the bottom of my question... that's how i did it.

Comment: I figured it out. I required the select2 css and javascript only on a partial (and rendered it with "content_for" from there) - that's obviously not enough. By including the script and css tags into my application.html.erb layout - everything works! Thanks a TON for your help :)